# Ktor Oauth with dynamic client ID and secret key

Tags: kotlin, oauth-2.0, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I am new to Ktor and working on creating a oauth functionality,
I want to implement Oauth feature but my clientID and SecretKey changes from user to user.

I tried to refer to following official document, but found out that I need to set ClientID and SecretKey during plugin installation.
https://ktor.io/docs/oauth.html

Which is not suitable in my case because I need to be able to set ClientID and SecrectID based on user who calls `/login`.

Any suggestions on how I could achieve it would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell me where you store the client ID and the secret?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman
It's stored in DB as of now so whenever user requests /login, I want to be able to fetch it from DB.

Answer (score 0):

The block assigned to the `providerLookup` property is executed for each call where OAuth2 settings need to be accessed. Also, in the block, `this` points to the `ApplicationCall` object. So, you can write the logic of obtaining the client credentials from the database there. Here is an example:

```
install(Authentication) {
    oauth("oauth") {
        providerLookup = {
            // val clientId = db.query("...")
            // val clientSecret = db.query("...")
            OAuthServerSettings.OAuth2ServerSettings(
                // ...
                clientId = clientId,
                clientSecret = clientSecret,
                // ...
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "`providerLookup` property is executed for each call" it's executed for each call of /login API and not for each API call, right?

Comment: Yes, that should be the case.

Comment: Thank you, let me create a PoC to test this.